# "cannot open directory" while restoring wordpress site using softaculous

Tags: wordpress, directory, softaculous

i got problem again ...yesterday my site was down and asked question but nothing worked...so i took backup of my original site through softaculous (c panel of hosting provider) and then removed it completely from wordpress....

I try to restore backup and now its error coming up "cannot open directory for URL" ..

I dont understand what i am doing wrong .....I got backup file on softaculous names

**wp.26_88074.2014-01-27_01-09-00.tar.gz** and i click on restore but its not working ...

so please let me know whats the solution for this...

i got data but cant put it back now ..

please help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have deleted the www folder of your domain.

Is it an addon domain ? If yes check to which path the domain points and then if that directory does not exist create one. And if it is a primary domain then check if the public_html directory exists.

Comment: i got one main domain (public html) where different sites into it ...all main domain .....no subdomains ...due to wordpress error I took back using softaculous and then installed wordpress again with same theme again .....and then restore it through softaculous and this error comes in ....so dont know whats wrong and where i am doing wrong ..please let me know how to resolve ....